# "a" vs "para" for purpose

Tags: selección-de-palabras, preposiciones

There might have been a similarly question already asked but recently when I was on Duolingo, there was this sentence

> Go to the market to buy broccoli with your daughter.

This was translated as

> Vaya al mercado a comprar brócoli con su hija.

But I though **para** is used for purpose so shouldn't it be

> Vaya al mercado **para** comprar brócoli con su hija.

Please, give me examples of when to use the 2

Answer (score 7):

The verbs "ir" and "venir" are usually used with "a"-adjuncts to indicate purpose. I'd even say that "a"-adjuncts are more usual in colloquial language than "para"-adjuncts with those two verbs.

- Fui al mercado **a** comprar brócoli / Fui al mercado **para** comprar brócoli. (I went to the market to buy broccoli.)
- Vine a la iglesia **a** rezar / Vine a la iglesia **para** rezar. (I came to the church to pray.)

We can even place the purpose adjunct before the one indicating place, in which case "para" will not work:

- Fui **a** comprar brócoli al mercado.
- Vine **a** rezar a la iglesia.